# Image Processing Rapid Experimentation Tool

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, octave

I am a relative beginner to Image Processing and trying to devise algorithms for a series of Image analysis challenges. I'm using OpenCV and Octave.

It seems to me that a lot of Image Analysis algorithms devolve into a sequence (pipeline) of well known Image Processing algorithms (e.g. Edge detect, Sharpen, Blur, threshold). So finding the right sequence to solve a problem is a function of experience and also just trying and tuning parameters for various sequences.

If this is correct, I would fully expect there to be an easy-to-use drag and drop tool (i.e. an interactive lab) for experimenting (creating and editing) image processing pipelines, easy tuning, and seeing immediate results?

*note: Assistance in developer tools and algorithms is appropriate to Stack-Overflow. Read the guidelines.*

Comment: I think "ImageJ" gives you a better "drag and drop/click" experience than GNU Octave

Comment: assistance yes, recommendations no ;)    anyway. most commercial image processing solutions provide these features. I don't know any decent free one that allows chaining drag and drop steps though. I'd also recommend ImageJ. It is simple to use, extensible, scriptable, free,...

Comment: I would recommend using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)